# flutter : Flutter Error after rebuilding app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Here's the error I encountered:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'firebase_auth'.
> Could not find the firebase_core FlutterFire plugin, have you added it as a dependency in your pubspec?
```

I have added the firebase core package to the dependency not sure why this error is  popping up again and again.

Comment: Can you show your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: `code` name: book_club
description: Book Management App for productivity 


publish_to: 'none'


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
  provider : any
  firebase_core : ^0.5.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

Answer (score 0):

cloud_firestore: ^0.14.3+1 did you add this to your dependencies?

Comment: i am not using firestore though just working on authentication

Comment: check your app/build.gradle page I think problem should be there

Comment: implementation, plugin may be minSdkVersion

Comment: yeah i think that might be the issue i changed the compile sdk instead of the min sdk

Comment: you can change min sdk to 21

Comment: Ensure that you have a firebase project created in the firebase console and all the configurations mentioned are correct